# Call SignalR Server Method in javascript function without event

Tags: client, signalr

I have a SignalR Server Method as mentioned below. I was able to call the method inside

```
 public void AddNotification(string message, string toUser)
    {
        lock (connectedUsers)
        {
            if (connectedUsers.ContainsKey(toUser))
            {
                string receiverID = connectedUsers[toUser];
                hubContext.Clients.Client(receiverID).addMessage(message);
            }
        }
    }
```

I was able to call the method from javascript using JS Client.

```
 $(function () {
        $("#sendControls").hide("fast");
        $.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:45210/signalr/hubs';
        // Proxy created on the fly
        selfHostHub = $.connection.selfHostHub;
        // Declare a function on the hub so the server can invoke it
        selfHostHub.client.addMessage = function (message) {
            $('#messages').append("<li>" + message + "</li>");                
        };
        // Start the connection
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
             $("#Endcall").click(function () {
                    selfHostHub.server.addNotification(username + " has disconnected call for loanid " + loanid, supervisorName);
                });
        });
    });
```

Is it possible to call Server method inside javascript function and instead of OnClick event. Kindly provide with any solution.

Comment: You can run code anywhere you want.  What have you tried? What don't you understand?

Comment: Can I Call the Server method inside javascript function and invoke javascript function from codebhind.

Comment: Yes, just like you're already doing.

Comment: Can you provide an example? Where ever i find i could see SignalR Server method is called inside an event in javascript and not in a function. Help on this will be great!!

Comment: Why do you think there is a difference between an event handler function and any other function?

Comment: Event handler fires during an action, but method need to be called inside any action. so calling SignalR Server method inside javascript method and calling the javascript method from Codebehind on satisfying certain condition is what i am trying to do.